# How to order a list in django with name?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Here I tried like this but it is not giving me the correct ordering.

```
class VAttribute(models.Model):
   attribute = models.ForeignKey(PAttribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
....

class PAttribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

from operator import attrgetter
qs = VAttribute.objects.all()
ls = [obj.attribute for obj in qs]
#ls = [<PAttribute: name1>, <PAttribute: nam2>]

ordered_ls = sorted(ls, key=attrgetter('name'))
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do a ***`order_by(...)`***?

Comment: apart from that, show some sample data in the `ls`

Comment: Can you please list your orignal input and the output you are getting? Syntax wise because it does not seem wrong till now.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I think we can't do `order_by` with the list

Comment: But, we can do it on QuerySet @D_P

Comment: How does your model corresponding to the Querysety look like?

Comment: `qs` is the queryset from another model and this model has related with FK so `obj.attribute` is from another model and I want to order that model

Comment: I can't do this with `class meta ordering` from model also since I want the ordering in this particular list only. @ArakkalAbu

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I've added my model also in the question now

Comment: add `PAttribute` too

Comment: @ArakkalAbu added on the question

Comment: @D_P Would you mind upvoting the answer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call **`order_by()`** as

```
qs_oder_by_name = VAttribute.objects.order_by("attribute__name")
```